# pound sign in CSV file are not read during PHP fopen

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, fopen, fread

I am having a problem, pound signs and single quotes are being read from a file as � 
My code is below:

```
$fh = fopen($_FILES['importFile']['tmp_name'], "r");
$contents = fread($fh, filesize($_FILES['importFile']['tmp_name']));
var_dump($contents);
```

Does anybody know how to fix this issue. I know its an encoding issue but unsure as to how to fix it. 
The file is a CSV file. 
Thanks

Comment: What encoding does that file has and what encoding do you use for your output?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`mb_convert_encoding()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) to convert the text from the encoding used in the file to your output encoding.